# Spring boot mongoDB aggregation piple-line no property found for type

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents called 'appointment', and I am trying to group together the number of appointments per day and populate an List of objects call AppointmentSummary, where there will be one object per day, I am using Spring boot to try and achieve this however I keep running into issues.

I have created the following three classes in the same package

**AppointmentSummaryRepository.java**

```
public interface AppointmentSummaryRepository extends
MongoRepository<Appointment,String>, AppointmentSummaryRepositoryCustom {

}
```

**AppointmentSummaryRepositoryCustom.java**

```
public interface AppointmentSummaryRepositoryCustom {

List<AppointmentSummary> aggregate(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate);
```

}

**AppointmentSummaryRepositoryImpl.java**

```
public class AppointmentSummaryRepositoryImpl implements    AppointmentSummaryRepositoryCustom {

    private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppointmentSummaryRepositoryImpl.class);


    @Autowired
    public AppointmentSummaryRepositoryImpl(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate){
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }


    @Override
    public List<AppointmentSummary> aggregate(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate){
        log.debug("This is a request to aggerate appointment summary between {} to {}", startDate.toString(), endDate.toString());
        MatchOperation matchOperation = getMatchOperation(startDate, endDate);
        GroupOperation groupOperation = getGroupOperation();
        log.debug("End group operaton");
        ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = getProjectOperation();

        return mongoTemplate.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(
                matchOperation,
                groupOperation,
                projectionOperation
        ), Appointment.class, AppointmentSummary.class).getMappedResults();


    }

    private MatchOperation getMatchOperation(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) {
        log.debug("Begin Match Operation");
        Criteria appointmentCriteria = where("appointment_date").gt(startDate).andOperator(where("appointment_date").lt(endDate));
        log.debug("End Match Operation");
        return match(appointmentCriteria);
    }


    private GroupOperation getGroupOperation() {
        log.debug("Performing Group Operation");
        return group("appointment_date")
                .last("appointment_date").as("appointment_date")
                .addToSet("id").as("appointmentIds")
                .sum("id").as("count");
    }



    private ProjectionOperation getProjectOperation() {
        log.debug("Begin project operation");
        return project("appointment_date","appointmentIds","count")
                .and("appointment_date").previousOperation();
    }
```

Whenever I run the it, I keep getting the following error:

**org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property appointment found for type Appointment!**

I believe the issue is happening in the following code segment, my understanding is that I initialize the different stages of the pipeline and pass them to the mongoTemplate and the 'getMappedResults' will map the fields from the two objects and populate the AppointmentSummary.class with the output of the aggregation pipeline?

```
return mongoTemplate.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(
                matchOperation,
                groupOperation,
                projectionOperation
        ), Appointment.class, AppointmentSummary.class).getMappedResults();
```

To note that the object Appointment does not have a field/property appointment. I added this in but when I ran the code I received another error message complaining of cannot find type date for Appointment.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use below variant of mongo template `aggregate` which takes `collection name` instead of `class`.

```
mongoTemplate.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(
            matchOperation,
            groupOperation,
            projectionOperation
    ), "appointment", AppointmentSummary.class).getMappedResults();
```

The reason was that when you use typed variant spring runs validation on the fields used in the aggregation pipeline to match the field names in the pojo and fails when it doesn't find the alias.